# OpenMP threads and SIMD for instructions without explicit for-loop

Tags: c, multithreading, parallel-processing, openmp, simd

I have function in my library which computes N (N = 500 to 2000) explicit rather simple operations but it is called hundreds of thousands of times by he main software. Each small computation is independent from other and each one is slightly different (polynomial coefficients and sometimes other additional features vary) and therefore no loop is made but the cases are hard coded into the function.

Unfortunately the calls (loop) in the main software cannot be threaded because before the actual call to this particular function is made, the code there is not thread safe. (bigger software package to deal with here...)

I already tested to create a team of openmp threads in the beginning of this function and execute the computations in e.g. 4 blocks via the sections functionality in openmp, but it seems that the overhead of the thread creation #pragma omp parallel, was too high (Can it be?)

Any nice ideas how to speed-up this kind of situation? Perhaps applying SIMD features but how would it happen when I don't have an explicit for loop here to deal with?

```
#include "needed.h"                                                                                                                                                                     
void eval_func (const double x, const double y, const double * __restrict__ z, double * __restrict__ out1, double * __restrict__ out2) {

  double logx = log(x);

  double tmp1;
  double tmp2;

  //calculation 1
  tmp1 = exp(3.6 + 2.7 * logx - (3.1e+03 / x));
  out1[0] = z[6] * z[5] * tmp1;
  if (x <= 1.0) {
    tmp2 = (-4.1 + 9.2e-01 * logx + x * (-3.3e-03 + x * (2.95e-06 + x * (-1.4e-09 + 3.2e-13 * x))) - 8.8e+02 / x);
  } else {
    tmp2 = (2.71e+00 + -3.3e-01 * logx + x * (3.4e-04 + x * (-6.8e-08 + x * (8.7e-12 + -4.2e-16 * x))) - 1.0e+03 / x);
  }

  tmp2 = 1.3 * exp(tmp2);
  out2[0] = z[3] * z[7] * tmp1 / tmp2;


  //calculation 2
  .
  .
  out1[1] = ...
  out2[1] = ...

  //calculation N
  .
  .
  out1[N-1] = ...
  out2[N-1] = ...
```

Comment: You could replace the individual hardcoded coefficients with an array of coefficients. That allows you to replace the duplicated code with a loop, which a good compiler may be convinced to vectorize with a bit of effort.

Comment: Unfortunately there can be other changes than only coefficients as well. Additional term or so depending on the case.

Comment: In that case I'd argue that the code is as bad as it looks and desperately needs to be rewritten anyway.

Comment: You need to say what those other calculations are doing. You need some regular pattern for SIMD. What compiler are you using? You will also need a SIMD math library. With GCC you will need `-Ofast` to get the SIMD math functions and `#pragma omp simd`. With ICC it will use SIMD math libraries by default (if there is no dependency between elements). You need to check the assembly to make sure.

Comment: Thanks for comments. I have to read a bit more about the subject and experiment the openmp simd features in general before trying to apply them in this kind of computations.